# Friendly URL to accept extra params in the "traditional way" (PHP's $_GET)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am developing a web application using PHP and I am using Apache's mod_rewrite for having "friendly" urls.

I have friendly urls like:

```
mysite.com/article/112
mysite.com/article/145
mysite.com/article/40
```

Everything is ok but I want to be able to receive extra parameters like this

```
mysite.com/article/112?referer=google
```

Actually if I navigate to mysite.com/article/112?referer=google I can see my page but I don't have the "referer" param in $_GET.

How can I address this?;)

**Edit
Solved :D**

I forgot to mention that my old rule was:

```
Rewriterule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article&article_id=$1
```

and the new one is:

```
Rewriterule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article&article_id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Show you rewrite rules because you are missing a parameter there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add [QSA] modifier to your rewrite rule

means Query String Append -exactly what you want.

Comment: My old rule was:

Rewriterule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article&article_id=$1

New one is:

Rewriterule ^article/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=article&article_id=$1 [QSA]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mod_rewrite I use to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule .+ %1.php [QSA,L]
```

Put in a .htaccess file, or in a  area in your web site's server config.

Answer (score 0):

According to apache.org

By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that with .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ somefile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is actually wrong, since the "?" does have different semantics in the first part.

Comment: you could change ? to / if you like

Comment: Exactly. But then it doesn'T solve the answer - you have to use the `[QSA]` flag.